# Montar List mapeado com @ManyToOne somente com alguns objetos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipse-link

É possível montar uma list em uma classe somente com alguns objetos?

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Curso.Aprovados", query = "select cur from Classificacao cl JOIN cl.candidato ca JOIN ca.curso cur")               
public class Curso {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Candidato> candidatoList;

    ...  
 }

public class Candidato {   

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer idCa;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_curso", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Curso curso;

   ...
 }

public class Classificacao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_candidato", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Candidato candidato;

  ...
  }
```

Gostaria que a lista de candidato na classe curso, só contivesse os candidatos que tem uma classificação, no caso esse Select contempla o que preciso, só não sei como carregar esses candidatos na lista de curso.

```
select cur from Classificacao cl JOIN cl.candidato ca JOIN ca.curso cur
```

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você pode fazer mapear a classificação no candidato e fazer a consulta from Curso, join com candidato.  Algo como:

```
public class Candidato {   

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer idCa;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_curso", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
private Curso curso;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="candidato")
private Classificacao classificacao;
```

...
 }

```
Select c From Curso c join c.candidatoList cl where cl.classificacao is not null
```

Isso vai popular a lista de candidatos do curso. Acho que isso resolve.

Edit1:
E supondo que a sua consulta estivesse com a lógica correta para o que você precisa:

```
select cur from Classificacao cl JOIN cl.candidato ca JOIN ca.curso cur
```

Você não precisaria de todos esses joins pois classificação é @OneToOne com Candidato e candidato é @ManyToOne com Curso, ambos são fetch type eager o que quer dizer que quando o hibernate carregar o Candidato, ele carregará junto o curso correspondente (se houver), sem necessidade de explicitar isso com o join.

Alguns links pra explicar melhor sobre fetch type:

http://www.devmedia.com.br/lazy-e-eager-loading-com-hibernate/29554
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601032/default-fetch-type-for-one-to-one-many-to-one-and-one-to-many-in-hibernate

Comment: Primeiro, muito obrigado pela ajuda.